# Split a long string in a small variable

Tags: javascript

I have an output from a string that looks like: How=areyou=doingtoday=verywell=thankyou.
How do i split the string so i can have only *are*? Or only *very*?
I can create a split that will start with How=  but how can i ensure that the output will be only *are* and not the rest. So that it will stop at *you=* but not store the rest.

```
function myFunction() {
var str = "How=areyou=doingtoday=verywell=thankyou?";
var res = str.split("How=");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to access the words in between `=`s. To do that, simply use `str.split("=")`:

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "How=areyou=doingtoday=verywell=thankyou?";
    var res = str.split("=");
    // res = ["How", "areyou", "doingtoday", "verywell", "thankyou?"]
    // You can then use res[1] to get "areyou"
}
```

If you only want to get "are", or "very", it is going to be much more difficult since there is no separator between "are" and "you" (and "very" and "well"). You would need to define a word dictionary of some sort.